# machine owner key details and predeployment options

Tags: debian, secure-boot

currently I am trying to get into the mechanisms behind secure boot, shim and machine owner keys.

What I observed is the fact, that the key, that I've imported via mokutil is permanent even if:

- the linux is being reinstalled (in this case debian 11)
- the secure boot store is cleared and reverted to defaults

as per https://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/secureboot.html Machine Owner Keys are stored in the NVRAM of the UEFI

However SHIM seems to be responsible for importing the MOK into the NVRAM, as it is not part of the UEFI default PK/KEK/DB/DBX store.

So my question would be:

- is it possible to tell SHIM prior to the installation (e.g. a customized version) that it should add a key to the NVRAM of the machine without requiring the user to interact?
- would it be possible for a manufacturer to place my key to the NVRAM?

Thanks in advance,
Matthias

Answer (score 0):

so the question regarding the MOK predeployment could be answered by
https://youtu.be/CGVubXFVLn8?t=1587 (thanks [@themole](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3899944/themole) for fwd)
german video - summary of the relevant part, as far as I was able to understand:
you have to go through "shim review", which is a process where you add your public key to the project code and you will get your - officially signed - shim version, after a review process.

I found this repo regarding shim review:
https://github.com/rhboot/shim-review

In my case it is not possible to go this way, but I am able to modify the UEFI default settings and content, so I will prepare a PK-Package containing my Public Key and update this post accordingly.